# A user seemingly modified a document after their account was deactivated

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, user-profile-service, security, user-accounts

Our company uses Office 365. A user left and our IT team confirms that her account was disabled in June. There's a document in SharePoint showing that she created it in April (ok) and edited it in July (not ok). As I have the approval/rejection workflow turned on and her edits were never approved, the document remains in a status of "Pending."  I ran all the audit reports SharePoint offers but could find no record of her editing this document.

Is there any way to figure out what actually happened?

Answer (score 5):

I would look at possibly a workflow that she initiated before she left that had a next step that was triggered in July. I think I have seen this behavior in approval workflows before.

Comment: Oh, good catch. I had not thought of that.

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke. We don't have any actual _workflows_. What I was referred to was the built-in [pending/approved/rejected status](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Approve-or-reject-items-or-files-in-a-site-list-or-library-d5931756-5315-4c4a-b89f-18947b6f7305). She edited a document which automatically (and immediately) switched it to "pending" and it's still in the same status. No one has approved or rejected it since. So I really don't think there were any "next steps" that could have occurred in July when she was already gone.